# Edit functionality using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have to make edit and delete functionality in dynamically generated rows using JavaScript.
I am stuck with the edit functionality. Though I have searched and it can be done but in that PHP is used. I don't need PHP. Can someone tell me how to make it in easy way?

I got something like:

<-----JS---------->

```
function Edit(){
        $('#edit').editable();
    }
```

But don't know how to implement it.

Code for dynamic generation of rows

```
function addRow() {
                    
var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var age = document.getElementById("age");             
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");        
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
      
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML=myName.value;        
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= age.value;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    //row.insertCell(3).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Edit" onClick="Edit();" id="edit">';
    //row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Update" onClick="Javacsript:editRow(this)">';
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Edit(){
    $('#edit').attr('contenteditable','true');
}
```

Comment: Actually I have edited the above code and I am trying to implement it if u can see in comments part but i am not getting it

Comment: Please suggest something

Comment: Probably I misunderstood your question. You need something like: row.insertCell(0).innerHTML='<input value="'+myName.value+'"/>' maybe? but if you need the edited value to be persistent, you must somehow save it, to localStorage (javascript based but if user clears his cache it will be lost) or with server side code which requires php and maybe mysql

Comment: you are welcome, was:   row.insertCell(0).innerHTML='<input value="'+myName.value+'"/>'    the solution you needed? if so, I will update my answer